# $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $S$ is a regular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, geodesic

I'm trying to comprehend the solution of the following problem, from the course in elementary differential geometry that I'm taking.

> Let $\gamma:(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a regular curve, and let $S$ be the surface parametrised by
> $$
> \phi(u, v)=\gamma(u)+v b(u), \quad a<u<b,-\epsilon<v<\epsilon
> $$
> where $b(u)$ is the binormal vector to $\gamma$ at time $u$. Show that there is $\epsilon>0$ so that $S$ is a regular surface, and prove that $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $S$.

Solution: Assume without loss of generality that $\gamma$ is parametrised by arc length, and let $T, n, b$ denote the Frenet frame at $\gamma(t)$. Since $\phi_{u}(t, 0)=\gamma^{\prime}(t)=T(t)$ and $\phi_{v}(t, 0)=b(t)$, the vector
$$
\left(\phi_{u} \times \phi_{v}\right)(t, 0)=T(t) \times b(t)=-n(t)
$$
is normal to $S$ at $\gamma(t)=\phi(t, 0),$ and hence $N(\phi(t, 0))=\pm n(t) .$ The geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t)=\phi(t, 0)$ is then given by
$$
k_{g}(t)=\left\langle\gamma^{\prime \prime}(t),\left(N(\phi(t, 0)) \times \gamma^{\prime}(t)\right)\right\rangle=\langle k(t) n(t), \pm n(t) \times T(t)\rangle=0
$$
since $n \times T=-b$ is orthogonal to $n$.

I understand the written lines above, but I don't understand why this implies that there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $S$ is a regular surface. Could anyone help me with this? (If I'm indeed not missing something, how can I prove the existence of such $\epsilon$?)

Comment: What definition of "regular curve" is used for this question presuppose? In particular, does that definition require any bounds on derivatives of $\gamma$? I ask because, without such bounds, this looks false to me.

Comment: @LeeMosher There is actually some ambiguity there. Sometimes $\gamma$ is assumed to be smooth, other times the only condition is $|\gamma'(t)| \neq 0$. In this particular case, I have no idea which condition is being used here.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you are definitely going to need to know that $\gamma'(t)$ and $\gamma''(t)$ are both nonzero, and continuous, and bounded above and below on $(a,b)$ by positive constants. That might be too much, but without something like that there's not much hope of finding the $\epsilon$. If you knew that $\gamma$ was defined on a larger interval containing $[a,b]$, then the boundedness condition on $[a,b]$ would follow from the nonzero-ness and continuity on that larger interval.

Comment: Just to clarify: The solution you posted is a solution merely of the geodesic portion of the question. The Inverse Function Theorem will tell you that for each point $p$ on the curve you get an $\epsilon_p$ that works on an interval $I_p$ containing $p$. But with a crazy curve, you might need infinitely many intervals and $\epsilon_p$ might go to $0$ in a sequence of those intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\Phi(u,v,l)=\mathbf{\alpha}(u)+v\mathbf{b}(u)+l\mathbf{n}(u)$, where $\Phi: (a,b) \times \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Notice that when $l=0$, our function coincides with $x(u,v)$ and $\Phi$ is also smooth. Furthermore:

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_u \Phi=\mathbf{t}+v\tau \mathbf{n}+l(-k\mathbf{n}-\tau \mathbf{b})\\
\partial_v \Phi =\mathbf{b}\\
\partial_l\Phi=\textbf{n}
\end{cases}$$

At $x=x_o$, $l=0$, $v=0$ we have the partial derivatives coinciding with the Frenet frame. Thus $d\Phi(x_o,0,0)$ is an isomorphism and (by the Inverse Function Theorem) $\Phi$ is smoothly invertible in a neighborhood of $(x_o,0,0)$, which we may shrink if necessary to write as $V\times(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\times 0$. Clearly $\Phi^{-1} X=I$, with $\Phi^{-1}$ being smooth. Thus, $X$ restricted to $V\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is a homeomorphism